# Date comparison in SQLite using ISO8601 format

Tags: java, sqlite, iso8601

What is the simplest way to filter dates in `SQLite` if they are stored as `ISO8601` format?

For example, dates in my database are stored as (for example) `2014-07-01T08:00:00.000+01:00`.

I am running a query to see if appointments clash. When I run the query:

`select count(*) from Appointment where (EndDateTime > '2014-07-02 08:30' and StartDateTime < '2014-07-02 08:45')`

This is a simple query to see if any other appointments start/end times cross over into this appointment. I know for a fact that there are appointments that should be picked up in this query. For example, one of my appointments has the following columns:

```
StartDateTime: 2014-07-02T08:00:00.000+01:00
EndDateTime: 2014-07-02T09:00:00.000+01:00
```

Yet I get no results even when I know I should be getting plenty. I'm convinced there is an issue with how I am filtering dates in my query - any ideas?

Comment: We need to see some data

Comment: Your query doesn't include the `T` and comparison stops there.

Comment: I initially did not include a `T` in the comparison because the raw query (in java) was `where date > date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");` However, adding a `T` into the string format resulted in java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T.

Comment: However I have manually added the `T` by referencing the `DateTime` object twice. Like: `"where date > '" + date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + date.toString("HH:mm:ss") + "'";` ... and that seems to have worked!

Comment: Use single quotes in a format pattern like `'T'` to output a literal `T`.

Comment: @Teifi So you are saying the statement you made in your question, "dates in my database are stored as (for example) 2014-07-01T08:00:00.000+01:00" is incorrect? If so, edit your question to be correct. And **be much more careful when posting**. You should have stated precisely the [data type of your column](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque On the contrary, perhaps you should read the question and comments fully before suggesting that I have given misinformation. My question is clear but somehow you have completely failed to grasp it, so please **be much more careful when posting**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literals you use for comparison in your query are not partial ISO8601 stamps:

```
select count(*) from Appointment where (EndDateTime > '2014-07-02 08:30' and StartDateTime < '2014-07-02 08:45')
```

The `T` is missing there between date and time. When the literals are compared, the comparison stops at `'T'` vs. `' '` and the time part is not considered.

You can use single quotes in a format pattern to output a literal `T`, e.g.

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
```